# Logger not saving all the log info as required - node js async

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, logging, winston

I have a winston logger which works great:

```
var systemLogger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)({
      timestamp: function () {
        return moment().format('D/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss:SSS')
      },
      colorize: true
    }),
    new (require('winston-daily-rotate-file'))({
      filename: 'logs/-system.log',
      datePattern: 'dd-MM-yyyy',
      prepend: true,
      json: false,
      timestamp: function () {
        return moment().format('D/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss:SSS')
      },
      formatter: formatter
    })
  ]
})
```

I call this logger in my program:

```
var systemLogger = require('./logging.js')

var asyncTasks = []

asyncTasks.push(function(callback) {
systemLogger.info('Saved the Updates', {
  'URL': url
 })
 callback()
})

asyncTasks.push(function(callback) {
systemLogger.info('Status Updates', {
  'Status': status
 })
 callback()
})

  async.parallel(asyncTasks, function(error, data) {
    if (!done) {
      process.exit(!error)
    } 
  })
```

I have simplified my code as much as I could, but the idea is that I have different log messages being generated throughout the program, I add them to the array and the run them in parallel.

Now.... this cause an issue. All of the log messages are printed to the console, however only one is saved to my actual log file. Why is that?

I tried to comment out the log messages and rerun the program, but still only one message gets saved form the above example. Any help will be appreciated!

Assumption - could this be because I am saving info to the same log file at the same time- but that is only two small lines so I assume if it gets printed in the console it should also save correctly?

Comment: What is `formatter` in `logging.js`? It is undefined in your example.

Comment: Also, please test your example code so we can use it right away to try to pinpoint the problem, instead of spending time fixing mising dependency, missing variables...

Comment: formatter refers to my custom formatter I use. This does not affect the results though. I missed them out in order to simply the code

Answer (score 0):

I've completed your code as much as I could, and got this. The code works fine and log both in console and in file without error.

Running node v.4.4.5 if it could matter.

If something is making the write to file fail, it's not in this part of the code.

`test.js`:

```
'use strict';

//Dependencies
const async = require('async'),
    systemLogger = require('./logging.js');

//Test variables
const url = 'redblueyellow',
    status = 'goldsilvercrystal';

let asyncTasks = [];

asyncTasks.push(function(callback) {
    systemLogger.info('Saved the Updates', {
        'URL': url
    });
    callback();
});

asyncTasks.push(function(callback) {
    systemLogger.info('Status Updates', {
        'Status': status
    });
    callback();
})

async.parallel(asyncTasks, function(error, data) {
    console.log('error: ' + error);
    console.log('data:  ' + data);
});
```

`logging.js`:

```
'use strict';

//Dependencies
const winston = require('winston'),
    moment = require('moment');

//Export
let systemLogger = module.exports = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.Console)({
            timestamp: function () {
                return moment().format('D/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss:SSS')
            },
            colorize: true
        }),
        new (require('winston-daily-rotate-file'))({
            filename: 'logs/-system.log',
            datePattern: 'dd-MM-yyyy',
            prepend: true,
            json: false,
            timestamp: function () {
                return moment().format('D/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss:SSS')
            }/*,
            formatter: formatter*/
        })
    ]
});
```